# formatting expiry date in mm/yy format

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

Hi I am writing an edittext in which I want expiry date of the credit card in MM/YY format.
The algorithm I want to implement is as follows: 
If user enters anything from 2 to 9. I change the text input to 02/ to 09/
If the user enters 1, then I wait for the next digit and check if the int value month if less than 12. 
Here is my code for this.

```
@Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
            String input = s.toString();
                if (s.length() == 1) {
                        int month = Integer.parseInt(input);
                        if (month > 1) {
                            mExpiryDate.setText("0" + mExpiryDate.getText().toString() + "/");
                            mExpiryDate.setSelection(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().length());
                            mSeperator = true;
                        }

                }
                else if (s.length() == 2) {
                        int month = Integer.parseInt(input);
                        if (month <= 12) {
                            mExpiryDate.setText(mExpiryDate.getText().toString() + "/");
                            mExpiryDate.setSelection(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().length());                            
                            mSeperator = true;
                        }
                }
                else {

                }

            }
```

This works fine until I press a softkey back button. The back slash never goes back. 
The reason is the second if condition is always met.
I am confused about how to solve this. How do I handle the back button inside aftertextchanged? Please help.

Comment: YXou can't delete the backslash because after XX/ to XX your scenond condition is met and then you append again a "/" -> its a loop

Comment: exactly what I was trying to explain

Comment: great, so look at my answer, just verify the input on each change and if its valid do your stuff

Comment: I am trying to validate the input this way: if (s.toString().matches("(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{2}")) but this doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: Then your regex isn't correct. But whats wrong with using `SimpleDateFormat`? Its made for working/ parsing dates.

Comment: Nothing, I am just testing it out.

Comment: Then look at the following link, there is a regex for creditcard expiry date verification well explained: http://www.robarspages.ca/web-development/regex-mmyyyy-regular-expression-for-credit-card-expiration-date/ :)

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. I want to have an automatic slash after the 2nd character is entered. If i entered 9 then it should automatically become 09/. I will post my code on some other question if you want. But this is not solving the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43265/discussion-between-user1051505-and-alex)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See my comment above to understand your issue. You might use this to verify the user input with your textwatcher:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy", Locale.GERMANY);
Calendar expiryDateDate = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    expiryDateDate.setTime(formatter.parse(mExpiryDate.getText().toString()));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    //not valid
}
// expiryDateDate has a valid date from the user
```

So in complete it would be:

```
String lastInput ="";

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
     String input = s.toString();
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy", Locale.GERMANY);
    Calendar expiryDateDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        expiryDateDate.setTime(formatter.parse(input));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        if (s.length() == 2 && !lastInput.endsWith("/")) {
            int month = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (month <= 12) {
               mExpiryDate.setText(mExpiryDate.getText().toString() + "/");
            }
        }else if (s.length() == 2 && lastInput.endsWith("/")) {
            int month = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (month <= 12) {
               mExpiryDate.setText(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().subStr(0,1);
            }
        }
        lastInput = mExpiryDate.getText().toString();
        //because not valid so code exits here
        return;
    }
    // expiryDateDate has a valid date from the user
    // Do something with expiryDateDate here
}
```

Finally the complete solution:

```
String input = s.toString();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy", Locale.GERMANY);
Calendar expiryDateDate = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
   expiryDateDate.setTime(formatter.parse(input));
} catch (ParseException e) {

} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
if (s.length() == 2 && !mLastInput.endsWith("/")) {
   int month = Integer.parseInt(input);
   if (month <= 12) {
      mExpiryDate.setText(mExpiryDate.getText().toString() + "/");
      mExpiryDate.setSelection(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().length());
   }
}else if (s.length() == 2 && mLastInput.endsWith("/")) {
   int month = Integer.parseInt(input);
    if (month <= 12) {
       mExpiryDate.setText(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().substring(0,1));
       mExpiryDate.setSelection(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().length());
    } else {
       mExpiryDate.setText("");
       mExpiryDate.setSelection(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().length());
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a valid month", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} else if (s.length() == 1){
    int month = Integer.parseInt(input);
    if (month > 1) {
       mExpiryDate.setText("0" + mExpiryDate.getText().toString() + "/");
       mExpiryDate.setSelection(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().length());
    }
}
else {

}
mLastInput = mExpiryDate.getText().toString();
return;
```

Comment: Also, It's a really bad idea to allocate a `SimpleDateFormat` in `afterTextChanged()`. It's better to create a final static instance.

Comment: It's actually better to use a `ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>` instance, because DateFormatters are not thread safe.

Comment: @Martin Macaroni: That doesn't apply here, because its all running on the UI thread, so its single threaded. A final instance of SimpleDateFormat would make sense in a complete class, but i was just outlining an example

Answer (score 6):

@alex solution above was good but it failed in a couple of instances. Like when you try to delete the slash, because it never really reaches if(s.length() == 2 && mLastInput.endsWith("/")) when you try to delete slash it will be stock at if(s.length() == 2 && !mLastInput.endsWith("/") and so it will give the illusion that the slash does not delete.

It also fails if the user complete the date i.e 08/16, and then take their cursor back to month and delete, it also fails if the date maybe some how ends up like 0/1. So I just made some changes to @alex's solution above.

```
//Make sure for mExpiryDate to be accepting Numbers only
boolean isSlash = false; //class level initialization 
private void formatCardExpiringDate(Editable s){
    String input = s.toString();
    String mLastInput = "";

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy",     Locale.ENGLISH);
    Calendar expiryDateDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        expiryDateDate.setTime(formatter.parse(input));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        if (s.length() == 2 && !mLastInput.endsWith("/") && isSlash) {
            isSlash = false;
            int month = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (month <= 12) {
                     mExpiryDate.setText(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().substring(0, 1));
                mExpiryDate.setSelection(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().length());
            } else {
                s.clear();
                mExpiryDate.setText("");
                mExpiryDate.setSelection(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().length());
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Enter a valid month", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else if (s.length() == 2 && !mLastInput.endsWith("/") && !isSlash) {
            isSlash = true;
            int month = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (month <= 12) {
                mExpiryDate.setText(mExpiryDate.getText().toString() + "/");
                mExpiryDate.setSelection(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().length());
            }else if(month > 12){
                edCardDate.setText("");
                mExpiryDate.setSelection(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().length());
                s.clear();
                _toastMessage("invalid month", context);
            }


        } else if (s.length() == 1) {

            int month = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (month > 1 && month < 12) {
                isSlash = true;
                mExpiryDate.setText("0" + mExpiryDate.getText().toString() + "/");
                mExpiryDate.setSelection(mExpiryDate.getText().toString().length());
            }
        }

        mLastInput = mExpiryDate.getText().toString();
        return;
    }
}
//wrap method formatCardExpiringDate around try catch or wrap the entire code in try catch, catching NumberFormateException. To take care of situations when s.length() == 2 and there is a a number in from of the slash
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
   try{
     formatCardExpiringDate(s)
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
      s.clear(); 
      //Toast message here.. Wrong date formate

    }
}
```

I would check Month again when user click on submit just to be extra sure.

```
String expdate[] = mExpiryDate.getText().toString().split("/");
if(Integer.ParseInt(expDate[0]) > 12){
  // Toast message "wrong date format".... 
}
```

I hope this helps....

Comment: Whats edCardDate?

Comment: @user1186061 that is what i name mExpiryDate in my actual code. Forgot to change it.. I have edited the code. Anywhere you see edCardDate, it should be mExpiryDate. Sorry about that..

Answer (score 3):

I used the solution of [Uche Dim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607860/formatting-expiry-date-in-mm-yy-format/40238715#40238715), fixed some issues and cleaned up the code.

So key improvements in my code are:

1. if a user tries to enter "13", only "1" will get entered.
2. when the user starts entering the year, after he has deleted the slash, a slash will be added so it keeps the format of MM/yy.

All in all this is almost like the Play Store's expiry field of new cards.

I've created a Kotlin class but usage is also added for Java.

CardExpiryTextWatcher class:

```
class CardExpiryTextWatcher(private val mTextInputLayout: TextInputLayout,
                            private val mServerDate: Date,
                            private val mListener: DateListener) : TextWatcher {

    private val mExpiryDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy", Locale.US).apply {
        isLenient = false
    }
    private var mLastInput = ""
    private var mIgnoreAutoValidationOnce = false

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        val input = s.toString()
        when (s.length) {
            1 -> handleMonthInputForFirstCharacter(input)
            2 -> handleMonthInputForSecondCharacter(input)
            3 -> addSlashIfNotAddedAtEnd(input)
            4 -> addSlashIfNotAddedInMiddle(input)
            5 -> validateDateAndCallListener(input)
        }
        mLastInput = mTextInputLayout.editText!!.text.toString()
    }

    private fun validateDateAndCallListener(input: String) {
        try {
            if (mIgnoreAutoValidationOnce) {
                mIgnoreAutoValidationOnce = false
                return
            }
            if (input[2] == '/') {
                val date = mExpiryDateFormat.parse(input)
                validateCardIsNotExpired(date)
            }
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            mTextInputLayout.error = mTextInputLayout.context.getString(R.string.card_exp_date_error)
        }
    }

    private fun validateCardIsNotExpired(cardExpiry: Date) {
        if (DateUtils.isDateBefore(cardExpiry, mServerDate)) {
            mTextInputLayout.error = mTextInputLayout.context.getString(R.string.card_expired)
            return
        }
        mListener.onExpiryEntered(cardExpiry)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun addSlashIfNotAddedAtEnd(input: String) {
        val lastCharacter = input[input.length - 1]
        if (lastCharacter != '/' && !input.startsWith('/')) {
            val month = input.substring(0, 2)
            mTextInputLayout.editText!!.setText("$month/$lastCharacter")
            mTextInputLayout.editText!!.setSelection(mTextInputLayout.editText!!.text.toString().length)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun addSlashIfNotAddedInMiddle(input: String) {
        if (input.contains('/')) {
            return
        }
        val month = input.substring(0, 2)
        val year = input.substring(2, 4)
        mIgnoreAutoValidationOnce = true
        mTextInputLayout.editText!!.setText("$month/$year")
        mTextInputLayout.editText!!.setSelection(2)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun handleMonthInputForSecondCharacter(input: String) {
        if (mLastInput.endsWith("/")) {
            return
        }
        val month = Integer.parseInt(input)
        if (month > 12) {
            mTextInputLayout.editText!!.setText(mLastInput)
            mTextInputLayout.editText!!.setSelection(mTextInputLayout.editText!!.text.toString().length)
            mTextInputLayout.error = mTextInputLayout.context.getString(R.string.card_exp_date_error)
        } else {
            mTextInputLayout.editText!!.setText("${mTextInputLayout.editText!!.text}/")
            mTextInputLayout.editText!!.setSelection(mTextInputLayout.editText!!.text.toString().length)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun handleMonthInputForFirstCharacter(input: String) {
        val month = Integer.parseInt(input)
        if (month in 2..11) {
            mTextInputLayout.editText!!.setText("0${mTextInputLayout.editText!!.text}/")
            mTextInputLayout.editText!!.setSelection(mTextInputLayout.editText!!.text.toString().length)
        }
    }

    interface DateListener {
        fun onExpiryEntered(date: Date)
    }

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun attachTo(textInputLayout: TextInputLayout, serverDate: Date, listener: DateListener) {
            textInputLayout.editText!!.addTextChangedListener(
                    CardExpiryTextWatcher(textInputLayout, serverDate, listener))
        }
    }
}
```

Usage (Kotlin):

```
CardExpiryTextWatcher.attachTo(inputCardExpiry, mServerDate, object : CardExpiryTextWatcher.DateListener {
    override fun onExpiryEntered(date: Date) {
        // TODO implement your handling
    }
})
```

Usage (Java):

```
CardExpiryTextWatcher.attachTo(inputCardExpiry, mServerDate, new CardExpiryTextWatcher.DateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onExpiryEntered(@NonNull Date date) {
        // TODO implement your handling
    }
});
```

**Caveat:**
The date will always be 2 digit long (e.g. December 4 will be 04/12, not 4/12) but if the user removes one digit from the date, it can become 4/12 so you need to run following method before validation:

```
/**
 * Makes sure that the date's day is of 2 digits, (e.g. 4/12 will be converted to 04/12)
 * */
fun normalizeExpiryDate(expiryDate: String): String {
    if (expiryDate.length == 4 && expiryDate.indexOf('/') == 1) {
        return "0$expiryDate"
    }
    return expiryDate
}
```

**Note:** `inputCardExpiry` is the `InputTextLayout` which contains the EditText.

Comment: it's buggy if i want to delete the first number from month of delete the slash

Comment: @ghita so you're deleting first digit from month (e.g. deleting 1 from input "10/") and this solution is removing the slash (i.e. the input changes to "10")? If this is so, this is expected. If it is something else, please provide more info so I could look into it when I can. Thanks

Comment: thank you `Sufian` for your prompt response. i have used the method that `Uche Dim` explained below.

Comment: Bug fixed which was [referred to by ghita](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607860/formatting-expiry-date-in-mm-yy-format/56768027#comment103036526_56768027).

Answer (score 1):

May you be you can do like this:

```
boolean validateCardExpiryDate(String expiryDate) {
    return expiryDate.matches("(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{2}");
}
```

which translates as:

a non-capturing group ( Non capturing group? ) of: 0 followed by 1-9, or 1 followed by 0-2
followed by "/"
followed by 0-9, twice.
...so this version requires zero-padded months (01 - 12). Add a ? after the first 0 to prevent this.

Hope it will help you..!!!

Comment: Its not working. I call this method as validateCardExpiryDate(s.toString()); It always returns false.

Comment: You haven't read his code and question properly, because otherwise you would have seen what's really his problem.

Comment: In question he wants formatting while typing expiry data in EditText but your solution is about validating which is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

`TextWatchers` are used to update an external property (e.g. in your `ViewModel`) each time an edit is made.

`TextWatchers` should not be used to modify the `EditText`s own text.

For Formatting input, you should use an `InputFilter` instead of a `TextWatcher`. 
Please try the following:

Include the following class in your project:

```
/**
 * InputFilter to ensure user enters valid expiry date in a credit card.
 * User is only allowed to type from beginning-to-end without copy-pasting or inserting characters in the middle.
 * The user may enter any month 01 -> 12.
 * The user can enter, at minimum, the current year or any year that follows.
 *
 * Note: `inputType` of the EditText should be `number` and `digits` should be `0123456789/`.
 *
 * Created by W.K.S on 30/07/2017 (Licensed under GNU Public License - original author must be credited)
 */

public class CreditCardExpiryInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    private final String currentYearLastTwoDigits;

    public CreditCardExpiryInputFilter() {
        currentYearLastTwoDigits = new SimpleDateFormat("yy", Locale.US).format(new Date());
    }

    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        //do not insert if length is already 5
        if (dest != null & dest.toString().length() == 5) return "";
        //do not insert more than 1 character at a time
        if (source.length() > 1) return "";
        //only allow character to be inserted at the end of the current text
        if (dest.length() > 0 && dstart != dest.length()) return "";

        //if backspace, skip
        if (source.length() == 0) {
            return source;
        }

        //At this point, `source` is a single character being inserted at `dstart`. 
        //`dstart` is at the end of the current text.

        final char inputChar = source.charAt(0);

        if (dstart == 0) {
            //first month digit
            if (inputChar > '1') return "";
        }
        if (dstart == 1) {
            //second month digit
            final char firstMonthChar = dest.charAt(0);
            if (firstMonthChar == '0' && inputChar == '0') return "";
            if (firstMonthChar == '1' && inputChar > '2') return "";

        }
        if (dstart == 2) {
            final char currYearFirstChar = currentYearLastTwoDigits.charAt(0);
            if (inputChar < currYearFirstChar) return "";
            return "/".concat(source.toString());
        }
        if (dstart == 4){
            final String inputYear = ""+dest.charAt(dest.length()-1)+source.toString();
            if (inputYear.compareTo(currentYearLastTwoDigits) < 0) return "";
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

Apply the `CreditCardExpiryInputFilter` to your `EditText`:

```
EditText expiryEditText = findViewById(this, R.id.edittext_expiry_date);
expiryEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new CreditCardExpiryInputFilter()});
```

In the xml, set `inputType` to `number`, and `digits` to `0123456789/`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_expiry_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789/"
    />
```

Comment: this thing doesn't work. As soon as a type the second character, it returns ""

Comment: What were you trying to type?

Comment: december month 12

Answer (score 0):

Add TextWatcher to your EditText & do the Validation with REGEX.

TextWatcher:

```
etCardExpiry.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (editable.length() > 0 && (editable.length() % 3) == 0) {
                    final char c = editable.charAt(editable.length() - 1);
                    if ('/' == c) {
                        editable.delete(editable.length() - 1, editable.length());
                    }
                }
                if (editable.length() > 0 && (editable.length() % 3) == 0) {
                    char c = editable.charAt(editable.length() - 1);
                    if (Character.isDigit(c) && TextUtils.split(editable.toString(), String.valueOf("/")).length <= 2) {
                        editable.insert(editable.length() - 1, String.valueOf("/"));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Validation with REGEX:

```
if (etCardExpiry.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                etCardExpiry.setError("Expiry cannot be empty. Format: MM/YY");
                return;
            } else if (etCardExpiry.getText().toString().length() < 5) {
                etCardExpiry.setError("Please check Card expiry & try again");
                return;
            } else if (etCardExpiry.getText().toString().matches("(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{2}")) {
                etCardExpiry.setError("Please check Card expiry format & try again");
                return;
            } else {
                // Passed Card Expiry validation
            }
```