# how to format credit card expiry date in mm/yy when entered by user

Tags: android

I want to implement algorithm like this :

As soon as user starts entering numbers for "MM" , it should give "/" after the user enters two digits of "MM" and then , it should let only enter last two digits for "yy". How can I achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string

Comment: You should use `TextWatcher` for this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40238715/2144352

Comment: https://github.com/sharish/CreditCardView this may helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set the max amount of characters of the EditText to 5, like this:

```
android:maxLength="5"
```

And set as numbers editText

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Then add an onEditTextChangedListener to the EditText to detect if the amount of characters is changed to two and did not change from three to two and remove "/" if a number before "/" is removed:

```
edit_text.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {}

    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, start: Int, removed: Int, added: Int) {
        if (start == 1 && start+added == 2 && p0?.contains('/') == false) {
            edit_text.setText(p0.toString() + "/")
        } else if (start == 3 && start-removed == 2 && p0?.contains('/') == true) {
            edit_text.setText(p0.toString().replace("/", ""))
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: can you check, there is a type here:  editText.setText(editText.getText() += "/";   its like a bracket is not closed.

Comment: By this approach, users have to enter two numbers at once replacing a singular number in order to get a slash to show up. I think you may need to read up on what "before" and "count" actually represent. [Documentation for onTextChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

so for example, as a user is entering characters one by one, before will always be "zero" unless backspacing a character, count will always be one unless the user selects a few characters and deletes them or pastes text.

Comment: @RiotGoesWoof Can you give me reproduction steps to show me what you mean?

Comment: had to crop a bit for the character limit, but hopefully that gives you a good idea of what I meant. Another problem with this solution more falls in line with "what if the user just decides to type 118. or 12018. Most users will see the "MM/yy" specification, but for those that don't, they could find themselves very frustrated very quickly with an EditText that now won't cooperate with what they want to do. This is why I generally use pickers when dealing with dates.

Comment: I had an earlier comment, but i deleted it because i was way wrong. I'm not really sure where the numbers I was getting yesterday were coming from when I tested this... Either way, your solution above should work, but problems do arise like the one I mentioned.

Comment: Yeah I prefer datapickers and timepickers too, but that's not what's asked in the question. I get your problem with the missing input validation, but I didn't add it so that the answer keeps one purpose.

Comment: this creates an infinite loop: changing text inside onTextChanged event triggers the same event over and over and over... again.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Edited the answer so this don't happen but kept the rest of my answer that is ripped in other answers.

Comment: You should make changes on "editable", not on edittext itself, cause that triggers TextWatcher events again and again.

Comment: Please add this code at the and off first if block ->

edit_text!!.setSelection(edit_text!!.text.toString().length)

Comment: it doesn't work correctly, and when you remove `/` and add third digit then `/` won't be added

Answer (score 14):

```
android:maxLength="5"
```

And set as phone to editText so that it can display "/"

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

on the textWatcher do this .... I will validate later for the correct mm/yy month year to avoid users input data like 55/66 max should be 12/31 but it should be validated for months with less or 30 days...

```
 @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


        if (editable.length() > 0 && (editable.length() % 3) == 0) {
            final char c = editable.charAt(editable.length() - 1);
            if ('/' == c) {
                editable.delete(editable.length() - 1, editable.length());
            }
        }
        if (editable.length() > 0 && (editable.length() % 3) == 0) {
            char c = editable.charAt(editable.length() - 1);
            if (Character.isDigit(c) && TextUtils.split(editable.toString(), String.valueOf("/")).length <= 2) {
                editable.insert(editable.length() - 1, String.valueOf("/"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I just implement a method like Uber credit card date format with auto check, autocomplete, auto move to CVV edittext.

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/credit_card_expire_et"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="MM/YY"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="5"
            android:maxLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/credit_card_cvv_et"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="CVV"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:maxLines="1" />
```

.

```
@BindView(R.id.credit_card_expire_et)
EditText creditExpireEt;
@BindView(R.id.credit_card_cvv_et)
EditText creditCVVEt;


@OnTextChanged(value = R.id.credit_card_expire_et, callback = BEFORE_TEXT_CHANGED)
    void beforeExpireEtChanged() {
        previousLength = creditExpireEt.getText().toString().length();
    }

    @OnTextChanged(R.id.credit_card_expire_et)
    void autoFixAndMoveToNext() {
        int length = creditExpireEt.getText().toString().trim().length();

        if (previousLength <= length && length < 3) {
            int month = Integer.parseInt(creditExpireEt.getText().toString());
            if (length == 1 && month >= 2) {
                String autoFixStr = "0" + month + "/";
                creditExpireEt.setText(autoFixStr);
                creditExpireEt.setSelection(3);
            } else if (length == 2 && month <= 12) {
                String autoFixStr = creditExpireEt.getText().toString() + "/";
                creditExpireEt.setText(autoFixStr);
                creditExpireEt.setSelection(3);
            } else if (length ==2 && month > 12) {
                creditExpireEt.setText("1");
                creditExpireEt.setSelection(1);
            }
        } else if (length == 5) {
            creditCVVEt.requestFocus(); // auto move to next edittext
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is previousLength here?

Comment: it doesn't work correctly, and when you remove `/` and add third digit then `/` won't be added

Answer (score 4):

```
EditText et_expiry_date= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_expiry_date);

et_expiry_date.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    String current = s.toString();
    if (current.length() == 2 && start == 1) {
            et_expiry_date.setText(current + "/");
            et_expiry_date.setSelection(current.length() + 1);
    } 
    else if (current.length() == 2 && before == 1) {
        current = current.substring(0, 1);
        et_expiry_date.setText(current);
        et_expiry_date.setSelection(current.length());
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

add these on youredittext.addTextChangedListener

```
         @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (s.length() == 2) {
                if(start==2 && before==1 && !s.toString().contains("/")){
                    youredittext.setText(""+s.toString().charAt(0));
                    youredittext.setSelection(1);
                }
                else {
                    youredittext.setText(s + "/");
                    youredittext.setSelection(3);
                }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Please don't just write the code, explain it to the OP

Comment: you need to add these lines on textchangelistener.. its working fine

Answer (score 3):

```
private static final String EXP_DATE_REGAX = "(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[0-9]{2}";

if (!edt_expiry_date.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EXP_DATE_REGAX);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(edt_expiry_date.getText().toString());

                        if(!matcher.find()){
                            edt_expiry_date.setError("Invalid Expiry Date");
                        }else{
                            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) % 100;
                            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;

                            if(Integer.parseInt((edt_expiry_date.getText().toString().substring(2)))>=year){
                               if(Integer.parseInt((edt_expiry_date.getText().toString().substring(2)))==year){
                                   if(Integer.parseInt((edt_expiry_date.getText().toString().substring(0,2)))>=month){
                                       str_expiry_date = edt_expiry_date.getText().toString();
                                       dialog.dismiss();
                                   }else{
                                       edt_expiry_date.setError("Invalid Expiry Date");
                                   }
                               }else{
                                   str_expiry_date = edt_expiry_date.getText().toString();
                                   dialog.dismiss();
                               }


                            }else{
                                edt_expiry_date.setError("Invalid Expiry Date");
                            }

                           // dialog.dismiss();

                    }

                } else {
                    edt_expiry_date.setError("Enter Expiry Date");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues and string manipulation needed with text based date entry just doesn't seem worth it here. What happens if a user goes back to the beginning of the string and starts typing? What happens if a user starts entering the wrong format? You have to account for a ton of cases without having a very good way of controlling what the user can input. In these instances, I'd just use a DatePicker [like the one in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321789/android-datepicker-change-to-only-month-and-year).

You can keep the EditText if you have your heart set on it, and just set the onClickListener to bring up the DatePicker when selected. I recommend setting these two fields on it though:

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

This way the EditText won't look like it can be typed in. My only suggestion or addition to the other answer would be a "Clear" button so the EditText value can be wiped if needed. To do so, just add it via the neutral button like so:

```
builder.setView(dialog)
        // Add action buttons
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                listener.onDateSet(null, yearPicker.getValue(), monthPicker.getValue(), 0);
            }
        })
        .setNeutralButton(R.string.clear, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                //check for a month value of -1 in onDateSet to clear current field
                listener.onDateSet(null, -1, -1, 0);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MonthYearPickerFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
            }
        });
```

Then to check and see if the field should be cleared, just do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    if (i > -1){
        et.setText(i1 + "/" + i);
    } else {
        et.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin for the format like

> "MM/YY"

you can use this,

```
et_expire_date.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            var working = s.toString()
            var isValid = true
            if (working.length == 2 && before == 0) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(working) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(working) > 12) {
                    isValid = false
                } else {
                    working += "/"
                    et_expire_date.setText(working)
                    et_expire_date.setSelection(working.length)
                }
            } else if (working.length == 5 && before == 0) {
                val enteredYear = working.substring(3)
                val currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) % 100//getting last 2 digits of current year i.e. 2018 % 100 = 18
                if (Integer.parseInt(enteredYear) < currentYear) {
                    isValid = false
                }
            } else if (working.length != 5) {
                isValid = false
            }

            if (!isValid) {
                et_expire_date.error = getString(R.string.enter_valid_date_mm_yy)
            } else {
                et_expire_date.error = null
            }

        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
    })
```

where `et_expire_date` is edittext for date input

Comment: @Vivek Mishra what problem are you facing?

Comment: Your if statements will not work if I enter 12 for month

Comment: @Vivek Mishra is your XML have these properties? android:digits="0123456789"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:maxLength="5"

Comment: Max Length would be 7 as you said in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version of @Goodlife

```
override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                if (s!!.isNotEmpty() && (s.length % 3) == 0) {
                    val c = s[s.length-1]
                    if (c == '/') {
                        s.delete(s.length-1, s.length)
                    }
                }
                if (s.isNotEmpty() && (s.length % 3) == 0) {
                    val c = s[s.length-1]
                    if (Character.isDigit(c) && TextUtils.split(s.toString(), "/").size <= 2) {
                        s.insert(s.length-1, "/")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use TextWatcher, example:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  // Do what you want here
  String myStr = s.toString();
  // Check if MM and do what you want
}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple Answer, set length 5 for mm/yy or 7 for mm/yyyy

```
    YourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                int len=s.toString().length();

                if (before == 0 && len == 2)
                    YourEditText.append("/");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```